Create admin account that only has access to select user accounts - Microsoft 365
Our company has been split and one portion is being sold to another company.   The buying company wants to import emails using CodeTwo.   Is there a way to create an admin account on Microsoft 365 Exchange Admin Center that only can administer selected users, namely users who will be going to the new company?  I want to give that admin account to the buying company's I.T. person so that he can setup CodeTwo migration.
Thanks

No, this is not possible.
Admin access is based on the tenant. While you can limit an admin in not being able to access all parts of the admin center, you cannot limit their access to selected users only.
The only way to do this properly is to create a new tenant, use a different domain name, and migrate the users over to that new tenant. Then they can do whatever they want to those users and the tenant.
That said, when a company splits, its often not wanted to use the same domain for both companies anyway, although I can perfectly understand having a short period where email sent to the old address can still be received.
For that, you will want to create a rule in the spamfilter to allow all these users to forward email to external mail addresses, and then setup mail forwarding to their new email address. You keep managing those users, not the other admin but only for the old domain.
Because they don't need to login to the account anymore, you can convert the mailboxes to shared mailboxes so you can remove the license. Optionally, after the forward, you can enable an Out of Office reply telling people to use the new email address instead.
